# In QGIS is there a keyboard shortcut to open/close the layers panel?

Tags: qgis

Is there a keyboard shortcut, or even something like a toolbar button, which would make it easier and quicker to open (and close) the layers panel in QGIS (2.6).

I don't see one listed under the keyboard shortcuts list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not come across such a shortcut, but rightclicking on an empty part of the toolbar area lets you easily activate or deactivate panels and toolbars.

I guess it would not be too difficult to write a python plugin with its own icon for your task.

Comment: Your solution is definitely better than going through the full menu dialogue, thank you.

Comment: Note that a double-click on the top of the panel also moves the panel from/to being docked in the main window. I'm sure this is obvious to many, but it's a new discovery to me.

Answer (score 10):

It's not built in (yet. I might just put it on my todo xmas list) however you can use some Python to do this:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

dock = iface.mainWindow().findChild(QDockWidget, "Layers")

def activated():
    visible = dock.isVisible()
    dock.setVisible(not visible)

short = QShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt.ALT + Qt.Key_1), iface.mainWindow())
short.setContext(Qt.ApplicationShortcut)
short.activated.connect(activated)
```

To have this always on you can add it to `.qgis2\python\setup.py` and it will be run each time QGIS starts.

Here is some code you can add to your `startup.py` in order to control bindings

```
from functools import partial
from qgis.utils import iface

from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

mappings = {"Layers": Qt.ALT + Qt.Key_1,
            "Browser": Qt.ALT + Qt.Key_2,
            "PythonConsole": Qt.ALT + Qt.Key_3}
shortcuts = []

def activated(dock):
    dock = iface.mainWindow().findChild(QDockWidget, dock)
    visible = dock.isVisible()
    dock.setVisible(not visible)

def bind():
    for dock, keys in mappings.iteritems():
        short = QShortcut(QKeySequence(keys), iface.mainWindow())
        short.setContext(Qt.ApplicationShortcut)
        short.activated.connect(partial(activated, dock))
        shortcuts.append(short)

bind()
```

This will take all the mappings and create shortcuts for them. Nifty!

Comment: +1 from me for the code, but I don't see any reaction using the shortcut on QGIS 2.6.1 standalone. Does it need the dev version?

Comment: No it should work in all versions.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but it is still not working. QGIS 2.6.1 on Windows XP and 7.

Comment: No errors at all?

Comment: No. The first one runs at least inside the python console editor (but not on startup), the second complaints there about `unexpected intend`in line 1.

Comment: Thanks Nathan. I'm watching this discussion so I can try implementing this when the issue is solved. I'm not sure enough of what I'm doing with Python+QGIS to try until then.

Comment: No success and no error log in Ubuntu 14.04 either. Did anyone get this running (without dev environment)?

Comment: I'm not running this on a dev setup, just a normal QGIS install.

Comment: Nathan - thanks. Having found my way into the Python console today for other reasons I worked out how to save your code and run it. I can't find .qgis2\python\setup.py though (Windows) - at least I can find multiple 'setup.py' files, and I'm not sure which to use.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Ubuntu, the commands found in the QGIS menu are accessible via heads-up-display (HUD).

To show / hide the layers panel, or the browser panel for example:

- click the ALT key
- then type 'layers'
- then click ENTER.

[image]

The layers panel will show/hide

Similarily, you can access any tool that can be accessed from the menu panel of QGIS, such as the buffer tool, and the MMQGIS buffer tool:

[image]

Comment: Thanks - personally here I'm on Windows - but I'm sure others will find this useful.